# Is it "invisible coat" or "invisibility coat"?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary, attributive-nouns

I’ve taken a test, and I’d like to know the answer to a question:

> **Complete the sentence using the correct word; make any changes necessary.**
>
> I would like to have an _______ coat so nobody can see me.

Which is the correct form of the adjective “invisible”: just "invisible" or "invisibility"?

Comment: If the coat were invisible, surely people would have a better view of the person wearing it, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 1):

Invisibility is a noun, while invisible is an adjective.

However, this question makes me think of the "invisibility cloak" from Harry Potter. Its an open compound word used for an item which makes the wearer invisible. An invisible coat would be invisible itself but who knows if it would make the wearer invisible too.